# How to write Iconverter for multiple converts

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform

Below is the code which im using to convert the values before binding to the listview. But here only the first 2 converts are working, the results for convert3 and convert4 are not getting displayed.please help me

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
        <local:Class1 x:Key="_converter"/>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView x:Name="Models">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label  Text="{Binding from_time,Converter={StaticResource _converter}}"/>
                            <Label  Text="{Binding to_time,Converter={StaticResource _converter}}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding from_time_tuesday,Converter={StaticResource _converter}}" TextColor="Brown"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding to_time_tuesday,Converter={StaticResource _converter}}" TextColor="Brown"/>

                        </StackLayout>
                        
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>



public class Class1: IValueConverter
    {
        public  object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var str = (string)value; // value is the binding data
            if (str== "00:00:00.0000000")
                return "";
            return value;
        }
       
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since the logic in each convert are similar , you could handle them in the same convert . The format  in class1 is illegal .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT , Sir "ve changed the class1 code  but then also label 3 and 4 values are not getting displayed . please help me,Thanks

Comment: You could share a sample so that I can test it on my side directly .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT, sir I've updated the code, please help me.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it works on the first and second label , I think the issue is caused by the layout . In your case , the **StackLayout** will not aspect the size of its child elements in runtime .

You could use **Grid** .

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="30"  Text="{Binding from_time,Converter={StaticResource _converter}}"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="30"  Text="{Binding to_time,Converter={StaticResource _converter}}"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" HeightRequest="30" Text="{Binding from_time_tuesday,Converter={StaticResource _converter}}" TextColor="Brown"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="3" HeightRequest="30" Text="{Binding to_time_tuesday,Converter={StaticResource _converter}}" TextColor="Brown"/>

</Grid>
```